# how to remove first word starts <br> we have to remove that one

Tags: java

This is my the input and output of the text

```
Input:
    ---------
    <br>dsbgvujgvbbjeb<br>sdgjvbbjsd<br>
output:
    ---------
    dsbgvujgvbbjeb<br>sdgjvbbjsd<br>
```

How to get this?

This is the sample example text.

Comment: post what have you tried, we will definitely help you.

Comment: sorry i dont know i am using startswith but it is find startwith how to remove.

Comment: How to remove? Use `String#replace()` method.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regular expression and the method `String#replaceFirst()` as follows:

```
 String str="<br>dsbgvujgvbbjeb<br>sdgjvbbjsd<br> ";
 System.out.println(str.replaceFirst("<br>", ""));
```

Comment: I checked the code and got output dsbgvujgvbbjeb<br>sdgjvbbjsd<br> .